# Whenever I select another item in combobox it display wrong value

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I created a combobox and populated it when i load the form and whenever i select an employee in the combobox it runs good. But whenever i select an employee with last name "BAUTISTA" i get the wrong employeeid. When i look at the debugger the employeeid of the employee which i selected is 100009 but the real value of the id is 10008.

```vb
Private Sub loansearch_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      ds = sqlfunction.getTable("SELECT * FROM TABLE")
 With cmb_employee
        .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        .ValueMember = "employeeid"
        .DisplayMember = "sname"
 End With
    Select Case search_module

        Case "LOANS"
            Loans()
        Case "DEDUCTIONS"
            Deductions()
    End Select


 End Sub

 Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
     Button3.Click
    Dim  type,employee,status As String
    type = "%" 
    status ="%"
    employee = cmb_employee.SelectedValue.ToString.Trim
    LoadLoans2( employee)
 End Sub

Private Sub LoadLoans2(ByVal type As String, ByVal employee As String, ByVal status As String)
    Dim ds As DataSet
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing

    ds = sqlFunctions.getTable("select * FROM TABLE WHERE employeeid=employeeid AND loanid="THE VALUE THAT I SELECT")
    With DataGridView1
        .AutoGenerateColumns = True
        .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    End With
    ds.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there more than one employee with last name Bautista?

Comment: This code has far more problems than just a wrong ID. It would never compile as shown. Please edit your question and show the real code.

Comment: Yes it has more than one employee with last name Bautista but different employeeid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace** line `ds = sqlFunctions.getTable("select * FROM TABLE WHERE employeeid=employeeid AND loanid="THE VALUE THAT I SELECT")`

**With this**: 
`ds = sqlFunctions.getTable("select * FROM TABLE WHERE employeeid='" & employee & "' AND loanid='" & THEVALUEyouselect & "')`

[image: issue]

Another issue:
your code provides `Private Sub LoadLoans2(ByVal type As String, ByVal employee As String, ByVal status As String)`

but
 looks like you call a different sub with just 1 parameter: `LoadLoans2( employee)`

Comment: actually that's the query output for employeeid='100009'. LoadLoans2 (type,employee,data)

Comment: put a breakpoint on that **ds=** statement. Whats the value of employee id?  based on your code youre not querying any employeeid, so it will just return the first id for the loan

Comment: Your replacement code is not good.  Now you have made the code wide open to sql injection hacks.  Better to use a parameterized query instead.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway on winforms from a dropdown.selected value? injection is not feasible

Comment: the ds statement is good. but my problem is whenever i select BAUTISTA and i try to look for the employeeid and value that i get is from the next BAUTISTA. 10009 is from another BAUTISTA but the real value that i need is 10008

Comment: @XkarmaX  Can you add a **screenshot of the combobox**? There should be 2 BAUISTAs  also, **the query you use to fill the combo.** Either youre selecting the wrong Employee record, or if you dont see two, then you are not selecting all of them

Comment: @EssKay sorry for the late response, i already solve this issue of mine. The problem is the special character that the employee name has. Bautista 1 has a dash(-), so i use .replace("-", " ") so the selection will ignore the special character without affecting the database.